# Powershell - move txt files from subfolders to root folder based on today's date

Tags: powershell, file, move

I have a beginner question.
I have a folder with a lot of sub-folders.

[image]

See example above, I want to copy .txt files only from the folder/folders with todays date only - and put them directly in this directory.

So in this example and only want to look in the folder with todays lastmodifiedondate.
I want also to check before that the file in that folder is not already present in the folder - H:\FOLDERS - then the move-command should abort.

This is what I have so far, but no files are being moved at all

```
$SrcPath = "H:\FOLDERS\"
$DestPath = "H:\FOLDERS"
$Today = Get-Date "$((Get-date).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))"
$ItemsToCopy = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $SrcPath | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt $Today}
$ItemsToCopy | Copy-item -Path $DestPath
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Henrik. As you know from https://stackoverflow.com/help, SO is not a free, bespoke script writing service. Please copy and paste as text the code you are trying to make work into the question so that someone can help.

Comment: This moves the files as I want.

Get-Childitem -Filter '*.txt' -Path "H:\FOLDERS\" -Recurse | Where lastwritetime -ge $(Get-Date).Date | Copy-Item -Destination "H:\FOLDERS\ARKIV"

But how can I add that I only want to check the folder that has been modified today, and add logic for check if the file already exists in the destination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, seeing as the expression `Get-Date "$((Get-date).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))"` is not valid, you can reduce the date call to just `(Get-Date).Date` where it returns the `DateTime` object at midnight time.

Fixing that should allow you to pipe directly to `Copy-Item` without having to save to a variable first as well:

```
$SrcPath = "H:\FOLDERS\*\*"
$DestPath = "H:\FOLDERS"
$Today = (Get-Date).Date
Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.txt' -Recurse -Path $SrcPath | 
    Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -ge $Today} | 
    Copy-item -Path $DestPath
```

You are also able to filter at runtime for *.txt* files only if that's the only files you intend to move.

Comment: Hi, that script runs but nothing happens, no files are moved out from the folder.

Comment: @HenrikRosqvist, are there any .txt files under the source path? If not, then nothing will be copied.

Comment: BTW, both `$SrcPath` and `$DestPath` point to the same directory.

Comment: Hi, yes there are files in the folders, I want to move them up a level, files contained in the folders should be copied out and moved out from them

Comment: @Lit, good point. Fixed.

Comment: @HenrikRosqvist, there is really nothing in the code that would prevent you from being able to not copy them. Would be helpfule if you post a directory listing that includes said files